# How can I make a variable dynamically change while on console python3

Tags: python-3.x, variables

I am working on a program and it needs to display the number of seconds that passed since it started. The variable is inside input() like this:

```
while True:
    something = input(str(x) + "seconds have passed. Please input the number in 60 seconds:")
    if x == 60:
        break
```

Is there any way to make the x change dynamically while on screen? So it raises every second and also updates on screen without the need to press enter. 
If yes, is there also a way to add an if statement that checks when the variable reached 60 and break the loop.

Comment: In IDLE this is not possible

Comment: Is it possible in terminal? or cmd?

Comment: yes it is possible in terminals

Comment: How can I do it?

Comment: I think https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61288221/move-the-cursor-back-for-taking-input-python is an appication of your problem